# Нужна ли БД для Telegram бота?

Tags: mysql, python, sql, база-данных, telegram-bot

Нужно написать Telegram бота с личным кабинетом в котором будет баланс пользователя и специально сгенерированная строка для реферальной ссылки. Можно использовать словарь, где ключем будет ID пользователя Telegram, а значениями его баланс и код для реферальной ссылки. Подойдет ли такое решение или нужно использовать БД, в которой вся эта информация будет храниться? Если нужно использовать БД, то какую вы посоветуете для бота написанного на Python?

Comment: К сожалению подробнее я о боте рассказать не могу

Comment: А где вы этот словарь собираетесь сохранять?

Comment: @dzhioev если это будет переменная, то получается в оперативной памяти. Это накладывает большие ограничения на его размер, значит его нужно хранить на жестком диске. Легче хранить информацию в базе данных, а не на жестком диске. А какую БД вы посоветует для такой задачи?

Comment: Думаю без БД баланс вы хранить все равно не сможете. сервер ведь перезагрузиться может, значит в ОЗУ ничего ценного хранить нельзя. А БД любую, какая больше нравиться, например postrgeSQL, если конечно у вас данные реляционны (что скорее всего так)

Answer (score 1):

Если объем данных не большой и нет желания заморачиваться с БД, можно использовать встроенный модуль shelve. Он создает встроенную базу, записывать и обращаться к данным в ней можно по принципу словаря

    `import shelve
    db = shelve.open(filename)  # создание/открытие базы
    db['spam'] = 'foo'  # запись в базу
    spam = db['spam']  # чтение из базы
    db.close()  # закрытие базы`

Comment: ухты, shelve - не знал не знал)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вообще, я считаю, если вы предполагаете использование бота широким кругом людей, то очевидным выбором была бы БД. А какая - это уже отдельный вопрос, который вы должны решить самостоятельно. Но я лично рекомендую вам SQLite. Мне она больше всего нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо что-то хранить. Очевидный ответ: да, вам нужна база данных. Можно выкрутиться и без неё, но зачем выкручиваться :)

Выбор конкретной системы зависит от ваших предпочтений. Если их нет, то MySQL будет хорошим выбором, потому что очень распостранена.

Короче говоря, если нет *особых* условий — держитесь тренда.

Comment: *"Можно выкрутиться и без неё"* —как вы представляете хранение данных без базы данных? Вопрос может быть "какую БД выбрать": где-то встроенная sqlite подойдёт,  где-то postgres, где-то  redis (nosql) нужен, etcd.

Comment: @jfs представлять то я представляю, но очевидно не рекомендую :) не представляю как можно интерпретировать мои слова иначе.